# How to make math logarithm functions in C99?

Tags: c, function, math, floating-point

I'm finally back at building my functions, which is what I'm doing before making the actual BPML language. In Part 3 - Math, I want to make some logarithm functions.

I never knew what logarithm functions were at the very beginning, but as I went deeper, I learned it and made this:

```
float log_num(int num) {
    int mult;
    float result = 0;
    for (int i = 0; ; i++) {
        mult = 10 ^ i;
        if (mult >= num) {
            result = i;
            break;
        }
    }
    return result;
}
```

`log_num` only supports `int` and `float` and `double` will have their separate ones.

Now I got 2 problems with this function:

1. When I tried to run it and use `100` as the number in the function, the result should've been `2.00`, but it gave me `1.00`.
2. Since the value to be returned is a `float`, I want the function to actually give me different values if it is not a power of 10. An example of it is `2 = 0.30102999566398119521373889472449`.

Q: **How do I fix problem 1 and how do I make the function work as how I explained in problem 2?**

> I want to make the function from scratch and not relying on other functions.

Comment: How do you expect to compute the logarithm of a number without ever *using* said number?

Comment: Since the only statements in the code that affect the value of `result` are `float result = 0;` and `result = 1;`, how do you think the function could ever return 2?

Comment: What do you think `10 ^ i` does?

Comment: `^` is not an exponential operator in C. It is an XOR operator.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/223239/discussion-between-bpml-and-eric-postpischil).

Comment: [log10()](https://en.cppreference.com/w/c/numeric/math/log10) is not an option? I mean, if you implement your functions in C you could use the C math lib. (which is part of the C standard libraries).

Comment: see [Building a logarithm function in C without using float type](https://stackoverflow.com/a/42108287/2521214) for some ideas ...

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> Q: How do I fix problem 1 ... ?

`10 ^ i` is 10 [exclusive-or'ed](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21034107/xor-operator-in-c/41205909) with `i`.  It is not 10<sup>i</sup>.

To find the integer portion of log<sub>10</sub>(num)

```
int i_portion = 0;
if (num <= 0) Handle_elsewhere();
else {
  int i_portion = 0;
  int n = num;
  while (n >= 10) {
    n /= 10;
    i_portion++;
  } 
  printf("%d\n", i_portion);
}
```

> Q: ... and how do I make the function work as how I explained in problem 2?

Below is a quick solution since C99:

```
#include <math.h>
float log_num(int num) {
  return log10f(num);
}
```

To code without `<math.h>` is fairly broad.  For efficient construction, we need design parameters.

First, be clear about base.  The standard `log()` is base [*e*](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/E_(mathematical_constant)), not base 10 as the question
implies.

Corner/Error handling: How do you want to handle negative inputs? Log<sub>any positive base</sub>(0) is usually returned as -∞.  For finite positive values, no range issues.  What should be returned for +∞, perhaps +∞?  What should be returned for [NaN](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/NaN), perhaps NaN?

Accuracy/precision:  Do you want the best result or willing to given up accuracy for speed or small code foot-print?  Why return `float` versus the more common `double`?

Performance: simply code that is of poor run-time performance OK?  Just code per [Logarithm Calculation](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Logarithm#Calculation).  Since the goal includes `my_log_i(int), my_log_f(float), my_log_d(double)`, for now, just code `my_log_d(double)` and have the the others call it.

Portability - how portable?

---

Sure we can code up a simply `float my_log_10(int)`, but without the design details, the result would be lacking in many ways.