# How to write a simple logarithm function without math.h?

Tags: c, function, math, logarithm, math.h

[This question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/64413407/how-to-make-math-logarithm-functions-in-c99) I have didn't fully help me, although it gave me a few details.

My current based code:

```c
#define e 2.7182818284590452353602874713527

double logarithm(long double dec) {
    // return log10f(dec);
    return result;
}
```

What I learned from the linked question:

1. Logarithmic functions use [*e*](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/E_(mathematical_constant)) as base. [Stated by the accepted answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/64413407/how-to-make-math-logarithm-functions-in-c99/64414888#64414888).
2. Also by the accepted answer, `^` is not for exponents (and I'm planning on making this syntax an exponential form, which might mean abandoning the `power()` function), rather it's an XOR operator.
3. Someone answered my question but got deleted. It is about the `log10f` source code, but it's kinda confusing, so not worth it for me.

Now the criteria I have for this function is that it is made from scratch, no multiple functions, and make it a simple sort (even though I doubt that logarithm isn't even simple).

The answer's code:

```
#include <math.h>

float log_num(int num) {
    return log10f(num);
}
```

Yes, fairly simple, but as a challenge, I want to not use the `log()` functions themselves though I'm still relying on `<math.h>`'s functions.

**Question:** What's a simple form of making a logarithm function in scratch without the built-in logarithm functions? *If* without using `<math.h>`, then how is that?

Comment: This is a math question, not a programming one. You want to know how to calculate a logarithm without a calculator.

Comment: @user253751 For starters, it is both. Asking this in [Mathematics Stack Exchange](https://math.stackexchange.com) won't do anything. Not even Code review will help.

Comment: What did Mathematics Stack Exchange tell you about how to calculate a logarithm?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you need something reasonably accurate, you could use the [Taylor series](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Natural_logarithm#Series) formula. Increase the number of iterations if you need better precision.

```c
#define EULER_CONST 2.718281828459045235
#define TAYLOR_ITERATIONS 20

double nat_log(double x) {
    // Trap illegal values
    if (x <= 0) {
        return 0.0/0.0;  // NaN
    }
    
    // Confine x to a sensible range
    int power_adjust = 0;
    while (x > 1.0) {
        x /= EULER_CONST;
        power_adjust++;
    }
    while (x < .25) {
        x *= EULER_CONST;
        power_adjust--;
    }
    
    // Now use the Taylor series to calculate the logarithm
    x -= 1.0;
    double t = 0.0, s = 1.0, z = x;
    for (int k=1; k<=TAYLOR_ITERATIONS; k++) {
        t += z * s / k;
        z *= x;
        s = -s;
    }
    
    // Combine the result with the power_adjust value and return
    return t + power_adjust;
}
```

Comment: Just a micro-optimization: you can start the Taylor iterations with `t= z= x` and drop the variable `s` using `z*= -x`.

Comment: Proud of this answer. I modified it to not just use *e*, but a new `int`/`double` should be used to be added as the base.

Answer (score 2):

**First remark:** All logarithms are proportional. That means if you have a function that computes the binary logarithm, you can use it to deduce the decimal logarithm or the natural (base *e*) logarithm. In particular, `log10(x) = log2(x) / log2(10)`.

**Second remark:** For a number `n`, `ceil(log10(n+1))` is the number of digits of `n` when `n` is written in decimal notation. Similarly, `ceil(log2(n+1))` is the number of bits of `n` when `n` is written in binary. Numbers in computers are represented in binary, so getting the number of bits shouldn't be too hard. This gives us the approximation `log2(n) ≃ nbbits(n) - 1` for an integer `n >= 1`.

**Third remark:** Counting the bits works for an integer. We can extend to a `double` greater than 1 by rounding it to int. For a `double x` between 0 and 1, we can use the formula `log(x) = -log(1/x)` and apply our approximation to `1/x`.

```c
#define log_10_of_2 (0.30102999566)
#define log_e_of_2 (0.69314718056)

unsigned int nbbits(unsigned int n)
{
    unsigned int count_bits = 0;
    while (n != 0)
    {
        n = n >> 1;
        ++count_bits;
    }
    return count_bits;
}

double approx_decimal_log(double x)    /* assume x > 0 */
{
    if (x < 1)
        return -approx_decimal_log(1/x);
    return (nbbits((unsigned int) x) - 1.0) * log_10_of_2;
}
```

This approximation has a precision of about 0.3.

This comes from the fact that `nbbits` is within `1` of the binary logarithm, and we multiply by 0.3 to get the decimal logarithm.

Answer (score 1):

While certainly not the best, I think a very **simple** approach would be to make a  function that performs a binary search through all possible answers until it finds the correct one.

pseudo-code

```
#define e 2.7182818284590452353602874713527

double logarithm(long double dec) {
  double answer = <<half of max>>;
  double step = <<quarter of max>>;
  while(!done) {
    if (exponent(e,answer) == dec) {return answer};
    else if (exponent(e,answer) > dec) { answer -= step;}
    else if (exponent(e,answer) < dec) { answer += step;}
    step /= 2;
  }
}
```

I would like to emphasize that this is not efficient, has not been tested, and might make your computer self-destruct.

Comment: Which exactly is the so-called "max"? Base *e*?

Comment: Depending on implementation, maybe DBL_MAX? Or perhaps there is a known value that is the maximum value that will be accepted as a valid solution.